# Device id is null on computer

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

From Ionic [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/) I'm using ionic native device plugin to get my device id.

The problem is when I test app on computer (in Chrome browser) device id is `null`. however when I run my app on mobile the it gives a unique alpha numeric string.

I want to know why it is null or computer. and is there any difference in device id and mac address. I think mac address is also a unique number for each device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Device` is never null.

If you run `ionic emulate browser` you will get

```
cordova:"4.1.0"
isVirtual:null
manufacturer:"unknown"
model:"Chrome"
platform:"browser"
serial:"unknown"
uuid:null
version:"58.0.3029.110
```

Native plugin only works when using cordova (i.e. executing on a platform: ios, android, browser).
But when you only uses the webview `ionic serve` then plugins are empty objects:

```
cordova:null
isVirtual:null
manufacturer:null
model:null
platform:null
serial:null
uuid:null
version:null
```

Comment: In browser why uuid is null. That is what I was asking. And when I run my ap on my real device and this is actual my device uuid.

Comment: Short answer is because the plugin does not support uuid at browser. Refer to the documentation https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device#deviceuuid (Supported Platforms

Android
BlackBerry 10
iOS
Tizen
Windows Phone 7 and 8
Windows
OSX)

Comment: I am getting uuid null even when running it into real device

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Device} from 'ionic-native';

platform.ready().then(() => {
   console.log(Device.device.uuid);
}
```

try this if you still need it.(I guess No, but leave it here for somebody met the same problem)